# Using bootstrap's navbar makes whole form clickable. How can I stop it doing so?

Tags: html, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap-3, flask, jinja2

So, I have a login form, and the form itself works if ran without a navbar.
However, when I add the bootstrap's navbar the whole form (and div)gets clickable, sending a request every time I click on it or on the email/password fields. I've tried to fix it, but I've not been successful thus far.
Any help is appreciated!

layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-fixed-stop" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BGP Monitor</a></div>
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('admin_control') }}">Admin Panel</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                {% if g.user.is_authenticated %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href ="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id="container">
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="{{ url_for('login')}}" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.email(class="form-control", placeholder="Username") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.password(class="form-control", placeholder="Password") }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

How it looks ( ignore it not being centred )
[image]

The page source when I open it on a browser:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar navbar-fixed-stop" role="navigation" style="border-radius:0px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BGP Monitor</a></div>
            <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">

            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href ="/login">Login</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid" id="container">

<form action="/login" class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST">
        <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="ImZhNTQzYmQ0MzllNWUxYWFmYWNkZjQyY2MyNDc2NDhiZTlhYTE0YzQi.C33d4w.ZRE0Lr6NmOLQ3CMHYkJ0fsfQj4k">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </div>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

P.S As Booboobeaker commented, I was missing the  after the Login/Logout buttons.
All good now!

Comment: You aren't closing the <a> tags in the nav bar for login and logout

Comment: Jesus, how did I miss that...Thank you!
It's solved now.
Damn, do I feel dumb right now lol
Cheers